# What are feasible ways of overwriting variables of SCSS files which are loaded through JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack, components

Say I have a component consisting of one JavaScript file for behavior, one HTML template file, and one SCSS file for appearance.

We use **Webpack** to load the component's JavaScript in the app's main JavaScript (e.g. through `require('./path/to/the-component.js')`). And we use the component's JavaScript to load its SCSS file (through `require('./the-component.scss')`).

The component's SCSS file contains a variable which has a default value (e.g. a minimum height: `$min-height: 400px`).

If I do not like 400px in all usages of the component: **How can I overwrite such a variable (for instance in the app's SCSS file*) to adjust the `$min-height` to `500px`?** Of course, since it is not a good idea to violate the *separation of concerns* principle, the component should not make any assumptions how its surrounding directories are organized.

So far I did not find a solution to this problem. But I am sure there are people who did.

*) and how (where) should I load such a file (usually, I load app.scss through app.js)

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're using require for scss files rather than compiling them using compass.

Comment: Since we always use `sass-loader` (+`node-sass`) in our web projects for the sake of simplicity. No need for compass. (+ we want the flexibility to replace SASS by LESS whenever we like to)

Comment: since you have the string of the css/scss file in RAM, since that's how `require` uses it, you can use a string replace() on it and re-feed it. you will have to dig to figure out how to get access to the require cache, but it's doable for sure.

Comment: Crazy idea, I like. However, for an acceptable answer it is a bit too hacky, since I actually seek a "best practice" solution not just a dirty quick fix.

Comment: yeah, i don't think there's an easy built-in way, and after seeing the other ideas, i think it looks pretty good/simple/implementable. fwiw, we've done something like that for language strings, having found no easier way to integrate into the existing delivery system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible to achieve what you want via scss simply because all instances of the component will have the same styles in the end (unless you use multiple classes like [Tyler Biscoe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41988943/1794463) suggested). In the end you will have one static css file for the component and all instances will share it.

Consider refactoring your scss to take the `$min-height` out of scss, make it a parameter of the component and use the inline styles to apply it. For React it would look something like this:

```
import './MyComponent.scss';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      const divStyle = {
        minHeight: this.props.minHeight
      }
      <div style={divStyle}></div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can just add the component with any width:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyComponent minHeight="300px"/>
      <MyComponent minHeight="400px"/>
      <MyComponent minHeight="500px"/>
    );
  }
}
```

This way you lift the min-height parameter up from MyComponent and let the higher components specify it.

**UPDATE:**

I guess you can lift the `$min-height` from mycomponent.scss and set it in parent. Say you have to set `$min-height` for `.my-component` css class, in a parent's scss file you could do something like this:

```
.large-component > .my-component {
  min-height: $large-min-height;
}

.small-component > .my-component {
  min-height: $small-min-height;
}
```

But again, this does not let you pass a parameter to a component, only set styles based on the component's parent containers.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I consider it a stopgap solution, since it seems to undermine the clear separation of structure (HTML), behavior (JavaScript) and appearance (CSS) I can achieve by writing three different files for those concerns, each of which 100% addresses exactly one of the concerns.

Comment: "I think it is not possible to achieve what you want via scss simply because all instances of the component will have the same styles in the end" The context in the structure (CSS classes of wrapping DOM elements = DOM elements wrapping the component's instances) may decide which component instances' styles are to be overwritten and which component instances' styles are kept.

Comment: I agree that this is violation of separation of concerns. Which might not be a bad thing. If you keep your components slim enough, keeping all the component's styles, structure and logic in the same place can be a huge benefit for testability, readability and general ease of understanding of your app. This also makes your components much more reusable. In short, I really encourage you to look into building your app out of many isolated components. [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html) is a really great example of this approach.

Comment: "The context in the structure ... may decide which component instances' styles are to be overwritten". Yes and that is what Tyler Biscoe's answer is about. But then your component has to know about the surrounding world and makes too many assumptions

Comment: I've added another possible solution

Comment: "But then your component has to know about the surrounding world" Not at all, the surrounding world needs to know the component. The component should not style itself depending on its surrounding world: the surrounding world should style the component depending on itself.

Comment: "In short, I really encourage you to look into building your app out of many isolated components. React is a really great example of this approach." I know React and use it (and like it). And of course my components are isolated, even though they consist of TypeScript+jQuery most of the time.

Comment: "But again, this does not let you pass a parameter to a component, only set styles based on the component's parent containers." That is perfectly ok. Seems like the best solution though there is no variable that could be used by the component's SCSS (which would be even better and probably the ultimate solution to me: I hoped I could "call" the component's SCSS from the app's SCSS like a function). Instead the component's styles are overwritten by plain CSS (i.e. low-level).

Comment: I guess it depends on your personal preferences then. Since I've started with React I stopped trying to separate everything as much as possible. I even seriously consider moving to inline-styles-only approach. To me the ability to explicitly pass a parameter to a component's instance is much more important than separating styles from everything else. But again, to each his own :-)

Comment: In my opinion, the designers of React came to a compromise. Inline styles had already been used by ExtJS, for instance, but also in those days, they did not improve anything. I will take a closer look at the guts of the SASS loader for Webpack and see if I can improve it to pass parameters (SASS variables) through `require`s/`import`s.

Comment: But of course, one problem you mentioned remains to be solved: How can the app style different instances of the component differently? I need to find a way of tying SCSS files to individual components' instances.

Comment: "I need to find a way of tying SCSS files to individual components' instances". Not to discourage you but I don't think that will be possible. We need to think of SCSS as static CSS it becomes in the end. For you to tie css to a component's instance, you'll have to specifically determine that instance with the css selector, which means basically creating an id for each component and a corresponding styles for that id. In that way CSS is more like a part of class configuration rather than instance configuration - it spans all the instances.

Comment: It is sufficient to provide one SCSS file (the contents of which select the component by context, e.g. CSS classes of wrapping DOM elements) per component instance (somewhere in the directory structure of the app). That is not that complicated. No need for an explicit ID. The compilation process (Webpack) needs to be extended to allow me to pass SCSS files to `require` calls (which is not that easy, since those calls adhere to existing standards).

Comment: But I have to admit: It is error prone since the CSS selectors which select the component's instance in its context have to be written manually.

Comment: On the whole, I agree with you.

Comment: As long as you have a finite and predefined number of component instances, that is true. Explicit ID and something like `.parent > .wrapper > .component` are essentially the same thing when you are singling out one instance of component.

Comment: Btw, here is a discussion regarding passing params to webpack require: https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader/issues/49

Comment: "are essentially the same thing" of course they are

Answer (score 2):

Would a mixin help you out here?
Say for example

```
@mixin set-min-height($min-height) {
  min-height: $min-height;
}
```

And wherever in your component you want to set the height or any property you just call

```
.app__view { @include set-min-height(400px); }

.component__view { @include set-min-height(500px); }
```

I believe this  approach is better than overwriting the variable since you are anyhow going to set a property to your component specific rules.

Comment: The mixin does not make it through the `require`/`import` statement loading `the-component.js`. Thus it is undefined in the component's SCSS file. + the component cannot rely on its existence.

Comment: I would suggest declaring the mixin at the app level so that any component of the app can inherit it. But why don't you want the component rely on its existence?

Comment: The component is meant to be 100% (app-)independent so that it can be used anywhere. There is no need for the mixin, it is optional. Thus the component cannot rely on it.

Comment: :D I think this a very interesting point. I underestimated the question.

Answer (score 0):

My thought would be to add a second min-height variable. `$min-height-2` for example, and assigning it a different value. Then applying that to a different classname that you would selectively assign to the elements you'd want to have a different min-height.

```
$min-height: 400px;
$min-height-2: 500px;

.some-element {
  min-height: $min-height;

  &.larger-element {
    min-height: $min-height-2;
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="some-element"> This element has min-height 400px</div>
<div class="some-element larger-element">This element has min-height 500px</div>
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but it violates the _separation of concerns_ principle in that it makes too many assumptions. Consider we need the component in three completely different projects with 30 occurrences of the component and 10 different values for `$min-height`. That means I need 9 additional CSS classes. A maintainability nightmare. The component should be absolutely independent of its uses and the default height should be negligible (overwritten in most cases).

Comment: One could argue you're already violating separation of concerns by editing styles using javascript. Your best bet is doing something like what I've outlined above. It's just sort of "how it's done". That being said, you may also edit the css directly using javascript: someElement.style.minHeight = '500px !important';  I do not recommend this approach however.

Comment: The styles are not edited using JavaScript. It is just the loading process which goes through the component's main file, which (of course) is a JavaScript file. The styles are edited by an SCSS file which lives somewhere in one of the apps using the component. Separation of concerns (the kind of "separation of concerns" which matters) is a requirement for the component's code (JS, HTML, CSS). Because the component's code should not be influenced by changes in its usages.

Comment: Gotcha. In my opinion the solution is to have perhaps a base set of styles for the component which are all stored in the structure you laid out, then perhaps allow for projects to include their own scss file that would further modify the component should it need to do so. Does that make sense? It's a similar concept to how people make small modifications to frameworks like bootstrap, or google's material-lite framework.

Comment: That is my plan. But if I define variables in the project's own SCSS file, how can I make them overwrite my components' variables? If I decide to modify Bootstrap, I can use `@import` statements which (as far as I know) enable me to change variables in other files. But using Webpack, `@import` statements are replaced by `require` statements which seem to be a barrier for variables.

Comment: In the scss files in the child project, I would create a new classname with a min-height value you that's appropriate for the specific project, then apply that class to the element in question. If it doesn't "take", then add the !important; modifier to the min-height value. I normally try to avoid using !important at all costs, I think it's messy.

Comment: So you suggest bypassing SASS entirely to make adjustments and carry out the overwrite by plain CSS? That is a passable way, even though I considered it as a last resort.

Comment: Couldn't you still use sass?

Comment: I do not know how to pass the variables through the `require(...)` calls.